# Connect to remote Windows command prompt via PHP

Tags: php, dos, windows-shell

I was wondering if there is way I can connect remotely to my Windows Server command prompt to apply shell commands through PHP. I am able to do this with my linux boxes through the libssh2 library. I'm wondering if there is something equivalent in Windows Server boxes.

My goal is to be able to remotely execute programs, or just simply execute simple commands like "mkdir" on my Windows Server by using PHP. Does anyone have a solution, or somewhere they can point me?

Answer (score 0):

I came around [this](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/devs/#php) many time ago.
It provides Remote shell and telnet amongst other utilities.It has a 30 day trial.

Besides that, you could also try installing an SSH server for windows and use ssh to connect to your windows server.